# Reusing Hibernate files from Coldfusion in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, coldfusion

Can one manually create Hibernate XML files for Coldfusion and reuse them in Java Spring at a later date?

The idea is that since I know Coldfusion, I could leverage this to facilitate my learning of Hibernate. Once I'm done learning Hibernate, I could reuse the XML files when I attempt to learn Spring MVC (and convert my existing CF project).

Comment: If you're coming from CF to spring ... you'll have a few bigger challenges than config files :: learning spring alone is an enormous job

Comment: @Eddie-B Indeed! I've been at it for the past while and I really have to exercise patience as it's quite the steep learning curve.

Comment: Don't give up ... IMHO Spring is simply fantastic. Good Luck! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can 'reuse' the hbxml because it has some specific bindings unique to CF class/datatype.

Having said that you may use the .hbxml generated by CF as a starting point.  Set `savemapping` to true: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSED380324-6CBE-47cb-9E5E-26B66ACA9E81.html

You should learn the annotations.  I think you can quickly pick up how to specify mappings in Java like how you would specify in `<cfproperty>`.